# React not rendering after props (list of object) is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have state in redux (a list of object), and I have an action to add blank object to the list. But whenever I dispatching the action React doesn't response to the changed props. I tried to log console in `componentDidUpdate`, `shouldComponentUpdate` it doens't log a changed props.

this is the action

```
function addNewBlankObject() {
  const newBlankObject= {
    field1: "",
    field2: ""
  }
  return {type:'ADD_BLANK_OBJECT', newBlankObject: newBlankObject}
}
```

this is the reducer

```
case 'ADD_BLANK_OBJECT':
      var listOfObject = state.listOfObject;
      listOfObject.push(action.newBlankObject);
      return state;
```

this is the redux props mapper

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state.listOfObject); //check if state updated
  const listOfObject = state.listOfObject;
  return {
    listOfObject,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AComponent);
```

I tried to log the props in above method, it does update the state, a blank object is added to the list, thus the props is changed right? why React doesn't response? Is it because the state is a array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state reference it not getting changed.Its remain same.
Redux do shallow comparison to decide to update the state or not.

State update in reducers should be like this.

```
case 'ADD_BLANK_OBJECT':

      return [
        ...state.listOfObject,action.newBlankObject
      ]
```

Please find [**`more here`**](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingobjectspreadoperator)

Answer (score 1):

Return **new object** in reducer, not mutate existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use componentWillReceiveProps, always put the redux state which has updates in the component state and with componentWillReceiveProps, update the state.

```
class AComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            listOfObject: props.listOfObject
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let state = this.state;
        state.listOfObject = nextProps.listOfObject;
        this.setState({ state });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state.listOfObject); //check if state updated
    const listOfObject = state.listOfObject;
    return {
      listOfObject,
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AComponent);
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` and `shouldComponentUpdate` is also not invoked, how can I update the state? and, isn't using redux mean the state is stored with redux?

Comment: what you are after is changing the redux state, and it always call componentWillReciveProps.
And yes your are right, if your component does not have any behaviour you sould use stateless component, but in the example i share, u have to store it in internal state.

Comment: I try to console the props in componentWillReceiveProps, but it doesn't log anything, maybe it wasn't invoked too. I'm afraid something in my code is causing this, I'll update the question if I found something.